# Is there any alternative for string.Join() inside Select statement of IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

[image]

SQL server does not understand C# inbuilt functions.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: *SQL server does not understand C# inbuilt functions* no it doesn't... What's your point?

Comment: cjld jcfld jc j ghyf fgu... That would never pass a code review 

Answer (score 1):

I would put `skills` as a collection instead and than `join` on presentation (Transform it in the controller or wherever you send it).

```
Sills = cjdb.jclsf.Select(i => i.sr.Name)
```